# random integers,removing elements

Tags: python, list, random, max, min

I have been trying several ways to remove some elements and can't seem to get it to work. The program needs the `[]` and `,`.  I have tried `nums.remove(x)`.

```
  import random
  ROWS = 7
  COLS = 1

  def main():
      nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      for r in range(ROWS):
          nums[r] = random.randint(20, 80)
      nums = [int(r) for r in nums]
      print(nums)
      print('The largest integer is',max(nums))
      print('The lowest integer is',min(nums))
      nums.sort()
      print('The middle 5 sorted low to high',nums, )


  main()
```

desired output:

```
79 30 39 33 41 43 53 
The highest number is 79
The lowest number is 30
The middle 5 sorted high to low:
43 41 39 33 30
```

Current output:

```
[22, 35, 39, 24, 75, 24, 33] 
The largest integer is 75 
The lowest integer is 22 
The middle 5 sorted low to high [22, 24, 24, 33, 35, 39, 75]
```

Comment: What are you trying to remove? Where is the code that does this?

Comment: Why not use array slice notation?

Comment: I'm trying to remove the [] and , to get the output posted my current output is [22, 35, 39, 24, 75, 24, 33]
The largest integer is 75
The lowest integer is 22
The middle 5 sorted low to high [22, 24, 24, 33, 35, 39, 75]

Answer (score 1):

You can print a list with space separation using a list comprehension:

```
print(' '.join([str(x) for x in nums]))
```

You can get the middle 5 elements of the array using slice notation:

```
print('The middle 5 sorted low to high', ' '.join([str(x) for x in nums[1:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can but it will take a bit more time. Printing a list like this:

```
my_lst = ['0', '0', '0', '0']
print(my_lst)
```

Will produce the desired result plus the brackets:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

To remove the brackets and put the numbers in a new line you can try printing all the numbers separately on a new line:

```
...
print(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2], nums[3], nums[4])
```

or use a `while` loop plus a variable:

```
num = 0
while num < len(nums):
    num += 1
    print(nums[num])
```

Unfortunately it will end up in a line going down instead of going left to right. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: This isn't really a good solution, especially with `join` doing exactly what you're showing with less effort.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `list.pop` to remove the largest and lowest nums in the list:

```
import random
ROWS = 7
COLS = 1

def main():
  nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  for r in range(ROWS):
    nums[r] = random.randint(20, 80)
    nums = [int(r) for r in nums]
  largest = max(nums)
  lowest = min(nums)
  print(nums)
  print('The largest integer is',largest)
  print('The lowest integer is',lowest)
  nums.sort()
  nums.pop(0) # remove first
  nums.pop(-1) # remove last
  print('The middle 5 sorted low to high',nums)


main()
```

Or ues remove in this way:

```
import random
ROWS = 7
COLS = 1

def main():
  nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  for r in range(ROWS):
    nums[r] = random.randint(20, 80)
    nums = [int(r) for r in nums]
  largest = max(nums)
  lowest = min(nums)
  print(nums)
  print('The largest integer is',largest)
  print('The lowest integer is',lowest)
  nums.sort()
  nums.remove(largest)
  nums.remove(lowest)
  print('The middle 5 sorted low to high',nums)


main()
```

If there are more than one largest or lowest nums in a list, try this function:

```
def remove_largest_lowest(alist):
  return [i for i in alist if i not in (max(alist),min(alist))]
print remove_largest_lowest([1,1,2,3,1,5,5])
```

Comment: I update the post if there are more than one largest or lowest nums in alist, hope helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Not for points.**

You can make your code much succinct if you know the right library. Granted, this is overkill but, hey, always fun to have an alternate answer. In my answer, I'm going to use `numpy` to generate the random integers. This proves to be much easier to do than your `for` loop.

```
import numpy as np

ROWS = 7

def main():

    nums = np.random.randint(20,80,ROWS)
    print " ".join([str(n) for n in nums])
    print "The largest integer is {}.".format(nums.max())
    print "The smallest integer is {}.".format(nums.min())
    print "The middle {} sorted low to high are {}.".format(ROWS - 2, ", ".join([str(n) for n in sorted(nums)[1:-1]]))

main()
```

This gives the following sample run:

```
50 51 78 41 58 37 38
The largest integer is 78.
The smallest integer is 37.
The middle 5 sorted low to high are 38, 41, 50, 51, 58.
```